# Is there a way to apply the free-tier discount to an existing CosmosDB resource?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing CosmosDB that I use for personal projects.

I just realized that in March, Microsoft introduced free tier and that would suit my needs. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-cosmos-db-free-tier-is-now-available/

Is there a way to switch an existing CosmosDB resource to use the free tier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible. You will need to create a new account, then use Change Feed or if you want something fairly simply you can use the [Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) to copy the data from your old to your new container, then delete the old container.